# BasicHttpBinding and MessageVersion.None

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding

How to configure XML web services client to use MessageVersion.Soap11WSAddressing10 for header namespaces. Currently it uses MessageVersion.None namespace, without me able to change it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do this using a custom WCF binding:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="Soap11Addr10">
          <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11WSAddressing10" />
          <httpTransport/>
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
```

and then reference that custom binding (by name) in your service endpoint:

```
    <services>
      <service name="YourAssembly.YourService">
        <endpoint name="test"
                  address=""
                  binding="customBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="Soap11Addr10"
                  contract="YourAssembly.IYourService" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

If you want to use this from a client, you also need to copy the custom binding configuration to the client's `app.config` or `web.config` and reference it there, of course (using `Add Service Reference` in Visual Studio will do this for you).

Comment: That is the solution, but still I don't understand why microsoft is saying basichttpbinding is compatible with WS-Basic Profile 1.1, and one can not set to use MessageVersion.Soap11Addr10